# When should we use proper name mark and how to type it?

Tags: punctuation

In Chinese writing, a proper name mark (專名號) is an underline used to mark proper names, such as the names of people, places, dynasties, organisations.

For example,
[image]

When we write/type Chinese, is it acceptable to keep using proper name marks? I do not see it widely used nowadays. Also, how to type proper name marks here (at chineses.stackexchange.com) and in a Word document?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, proper name marks is a part of archaic Chinese. It's no longer used in modern Chinese. In modern Chinese, only book name, music name, movie names, and etc. will be marked with special punctuation, such as 《新约全书》. You can type it by switch to most Chinese input method and use '<' and '>' key on the keyboard.

As for using proper name marks, usually you can just use an underline or a double underline. Doing it in Word is pretty straight forward. In StackExchange could be complicated, you have to use HTML code, such as `<u>测试<\u>`. For double underline, it's even more complicated, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643614/double-underline-tag) .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are not popular in simplified Chinese nowadays, but you definitely can use it whenever you want. Just like the pilcrow ¶ in English.

The sad fact is no way to input these symbols, :(, you can only add them in a text processing softwares as bottom borders.